# Pipfile.lock out of date

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a large django project to heroku. I installed Heroku CLI, logged in, created an app and ran:

`git push heroku master`

I have a Pipfile and requirements.txt already set up. I added a runtime.txt to specify that I need python 2.7. This is also in the Pipfile. This is what I get from pushing to heroku:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 12159, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4853/4853), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12159/12159), 20.94 MiB | 1.82 MiB/s, done.
Total 12159 (delta 6859), reused 12036 (delta 6751)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.4
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 11.8.2…
remote:        Your Pipfile.lock (3b2ba9) is out of date. Expected: (83a5b4).
remote:        Aborting deploy.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to camp-infinity.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/camp-infinity.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/camp-infinity.git'
```

For some reason it tries to install python 3, and it also doesn't like my Pipfile.lock file. I've tried deleting it and generating it again with pipenv install but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Is your local Pipenv installation also 11.8.2?

Comment: local Pipenv version is different. But "11.8.2" is hardcoded in https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/pipenv

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, the only solution was to remove the Pipfile.lock file and committing that

Comment: This problem can also be caused by `pipenv install -e .`. If you need this for running tests on travis, try to add `pipenv install -e .` to the `install` entry in your `.travis.yaml`.

Answer (score 90):

Experienced the same problem while working on a project, in the branch you are pushing to Heroku, run

```
pipenv lock
```

and it will update the Pipfile.lock file. :)

Answer (score 8):

Updating my pipenv: `pip install pipenv --upgrade`
then doing: `pipenv lock`
then do a commit

fixed this for me

Answer (score 3):

I removed the `Pipfile.lock` and commited it's deletion. Heroku's build process complained about it not being there, but it did deploy successfully...

```
-----> Python app detected
 !     No 'Pipfile.lock' found! We recommend you commit this into your repository.
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 11.8.2…
       Installing dependencies from Pipfile…
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> worker
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 189.9M
-----> Launching...
       Released v5
```

Comment: That sort of defeats the purpose of _having the lockfile_, which is to make sure development and production are in sync.

Answer (score 3):

If there is already a Pipfile created, delete it and push deploy it again. It should re-install your dependencies. That is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to deal with this is to run :
`pipenv lock`
and then `git commit -am "updated pipfile"`,
`git push && git push heroku master`

These commands do the same exact thing as some of the other commands listed in other answer but well, these might do it a bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same problem today, so I solved in the way, the guy mentioned below, by updating my pipenv - `pip install pipenv --upgrade` and then hitting `pipenv lock`. This is the way to go, and solves the most cases. Also, after that do not forget to git add, commit and to push to heroku! Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should provide either a:

1. `Pipfile` and corresponding `Pipfile.lock`

or

2. `requirements.txt` (and optionally `runtime.txt`)

If you are using a `Pipfile` then `git rm requirements.txt runtime.txt` and make sure to `git add Pipfile Pipfile.lock`. `git commit` and then try your `git push` to heroku.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes

Comment: I removed requirements.txt and runtime.txt and tried again. Nothing happened. I made sure that the correct python version is specified in Pipfile and then ran pipnv lock and tried again. Nothing happened. It still tries to install python 3 and fails with the same message.

Comment: Are the proper `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` committed to git before you push to heroku?

Comment: Yes, they are commited

Comment: Can you post your `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was due to a symbolic link pointing to Pipfile.lock.

After cloning the repo on my local mac OS environment, for some reasons, the original link was kind of broken and this resulted in `Your Pipfile.lock (3b2ba9) is out of date. Expected: (83a5b4)` when pushing to Heroku.

Just deleting the "old" symbolic link and recreating it from my local env solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Heroku CLI, I was running `git push heroku master` from a local branch that was not `master`, when this exact error appeared:

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
remote:        Your Pipfile.lock (38bf21) is out of date. Expected: (e4987e).
remote:        Aborting deploy.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

Deploying from the `master` branch fixed it.

If you want to push a local branch to the Heroku master that is not `master`, run `git push heroku branchname:master`.

Answer (score -2):

Just another tip: Make sure to do a `git add .` and `git commit -m "whatever"` if you've made updates to your `Pipfile.lock` and don't see any changes. :)