# Outdated Pipfile.lock

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a large django project to heroku. I installed Heroku CLI, logged in, created an app and ran:

```
git push heroku master
```

I have a Pipfile and requirements.txt already set up. I added a runtime.txt to specify that I need python 2.7. This is also in the Pipfile. This is what I get from pushing to heroku:

```
Counting objects: 12159, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4853/4853), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12159/12159), 20.94 MiB | 1.82 MiB/s, done.
Total 12159 (delta 6859), reused 12036 (delta 6751)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.4
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 11.8.2…
remote:        Your Pipfile.lock (3b2ba9) is out of date. Expected: (83a5b4).
remote:        Aborting deploy.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to camp-infinity.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/camp-infinity.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/camp-infinity.git'
```

I'm not sure why it tries to install python 3, and it also doesn't like my Pipfile.lock file. I've tried deleting it and generating it again with pipenv install but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/76, it might help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pipfile.lock out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460486/pipfile-lock-out-of-date)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have initialised your environment in Python 2.X with `pipenv --two`, then - given your code runs locally and all dependencies are specified in your Pipfile - run `pipenv install` and commit all changes including the `Pipfile.lock` to your local git repo (`git add * && git commit -m "your message"`). Finally push to heroku. Hope it now builds correctly.